# React Native Okta SSO 403

Tags: react-native, webview, single-sign-on, fetch, okta-api

I am trying to build an SSO login flow on a React Native app using Okta's oauth 2.0 api.

Here is the flow that I am trying to achieve:

(1) webview renders login page from /oauth2/:authorizationServerId/v1/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=query&client_id=***&scope=***&redirect_uri=___. 
(2) user logs in.
(3) webview renders redirect_uri with authorization code in url.
(4) I extract authorization code and send it along with client id, client secret, and other necessary params to /oauth2/:authorizationServerId/v1/token.
(5) endpoint responds with accessToken.

I am able to get the accessToken through this process using postman and curl so I know that this works. I have also verified that this exact flow works on a Xamarin app.

However, when trying to hit the /oauth2/:authorizationServerId/v1/token route from my React Native app after getting the authorization code, I always get a 403 without an error message.

I am using fetch for my api calls and used the not-CRNA way of creating my app.

Has anyone ever come across this issue before? In general, has anyone been able to get this type of Okta flow to work with React Native?

At first I thought it was a CORS issue but followed the CORS test [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors.html) and verified that this was not the case.

I also thought it was an issue with making a fetch request and rendering a webview at the same time. I built my own Okta sign-in page so I wouldn't have to use a webview and used [this](https://github.com/SohaibAjmal/Okta-OpenId-Scripts) flow but got the same 403.

Any and all help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually with a 403 you will receive an error message with it. Can you provide that to help us diagnose what the underlying issue could be?

Comment: @jmelberg there was neither an error message nor an error code from Okta which makes this even more bizarre.

Comment: any progress on this?