# Okta in React Native on IOS 10

Tags: okta, okta-api

Has anyone worked with Okta from React native, and successfully implemented?

We've got a web app that has implemented the okta widget successfully, but the react native app needs to use the lower level api.

From my understanding, the widget doesnt work with ios 10
We implemented the 'resource owner' flow from the BE api, but that created a dependency and now blocks the FE, since the okta api has so many functions.

It seems like a rabbit hole with wrapping the okta apis.
Any thoughts?

There are other open questions like this that make me nervous - [React Native Okta SSO 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853820/react-native-okta-sso-403) .

*update*
I really don't like the idea of creating BE endpoints to wrap the okta endpoints for the front end, using the resource-owner flow. It feels really hacky and not maintainable.

We found this mentioned in the oidc library - https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-ios#handle-the-redirect
I've asked the RN developer to try this or some other lower level library to implement it, since the discussion is all theoretical until he writes some code =\

*update*
The RN developer said he was able to build for iOS 10 - I'm not sure exactly which library he is using.  But I'll post an official answer here when I get more detail.

Comment: I was able to make our React Native SDK work with iOS 11. I didn't try with iOS 10. See the tutorial I wrote about it at https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/11/14/react-native-login.

Comment: Thanks Matt - my FE dev said there is something about the bindings that aren't compatible with the older iOS. I'll update the post with more detail as we figure it out.  Also - I'm a big fan of jhipster. Thanks for contributing so much the OS community.